What does congruence of two points mean in Abelian variety?
Let $\mathcal{A}/K$ be an Abelian variety over a number field $K$ and $\phi$ is an embedding of it into some projective space. I have a confusion what does it mean to say
$$
P \equiv Q \hspace{0.1cm} ( mod \hspace{0.1cm}  \mathfrak{P}).
$$
where $\mathfrak{P}$ is a prime ideal in $K$.
Does it mean that we are looking the image of P and Q under the embedding and then comparing the coordinates modulo the prime or we are looking at the image of point P-Q and comparing it's coordinate with the image of identity of the Abelian variety.

Concretely, for reducing mod $\mathfrak{P}$, the authors are probably picturing something like this: scale the coordinates (under your choice of projective embedding) of a point until all coordinates are in $\mathcal{O}_K$ and not all of them are in $\mathfrak{P}$. Then reduce the coordinates mod $\mathfrak{P}$. This gives you a tuple in $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{P})$ which doesn't depend on your scaling.
In particular, you can do this to $P-Q$, so you can ask if the class of the reduction of $P-Q$ is the class of the reduction of $0$. However, it's not true that for any abelian variety over a number field and any $\mathfrak{P}$, that the subset of $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{P})$ that you get by reducing points in this way is the group of points of an abelian variety (or that it is a group at all under the "reduction of +") -- having this property is called "good reduction" at $\mathfrak{P}$. Even when there is good reduction, it's not clear that the group structure is independent of the choice of projective embedding. (In fact both of these things happen to be true for almost all $\mathfrak{P}$, although this is not easy -- in your case, it looks like $\phi$ is chosen ahead of time, so you only have to worry about the first subtlety and not the second.)
To make things more precise, typically one speaks of picking a model of the abelian variety over the ring of integers of $\mathcal{O}_K$, and there are preferred models to pick. You can learn about this in the beautiful book Néron Models, by Bosch, Lütkebohmert, and Raynaud.

"although this is not easy" -- on reflection, the second claim about being independent of the embedding almost-everywhere isn't bad -- given two different projective embeddings, pick an isomorphism between the ambient varieties and extend it to a map of the underlying projective spaces, your isomorphism has finitely many polynomials with finitely many denominators and therefore works mod $\mathfrak{P}$ for almost all $\mathfrak{P}$. This argument is called "spreading out." Of course it's not useful at any particular $\mathfrak{P}$.
